# Finding an element in a infinite unsorted doubly linked list

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, linked-lists

Is there any way to find an element in an unsorted doubly linked list given an element and pointer from which we can navigate? (we can't use head/tail pointers since the list is infinite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite/unbounded in both directions?
Zig-zag.

Comment: Would that work something like this? - steps in powers of 2 in alternating directions (2 steps left, 4 steps right,.....until we find the element)?

Comment: @Sridhar No, just keep two pointers, _left_ and _right_ and decrement _left_ and increment _right_.

Comment: @PålGD that would work of course, but the question suggested "an element and pointer" in singular.

Comment: @Sridhar indeed!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The complexity would be exponential right?

Comment: @Sridhar No, I do not think it will be exponential. If we start at position $0$, and move $+1, -2, +3, -4,  +5, \dots$ we reach positions $+1, -1, +2, -2, +3, \dots$. Adding the total number of steps $1+2+3+\dots+n$ we get a quadratic function. Moving in powers of two will be slightly more efficient than that?

Comment: @HendrikJan It reads _"given an element and pointer from which we can navigate"_ — it doesn't say anything about how many pointers at most you can keep in memory?

Comment: @PålGD Yes, I agree, it is a matter of interpretation. I read it as if given an "abstract" data structure in which we can instruct a single 'internal' pointer to be moved along the list.